# How can I search a row using a value which is in a jsonB column?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying this since the whole day but unable to find a solution.

I have a Postgres table items which has a jsonb column named item_stats. It keeps value like

{"barcodes": [{"qty": "1", "code": "3123123123"}, {"qty": "60", "code": "100123123596"}], "barCodeId": "09048921312"}

I am using Spring data JPA in my Spring boot service and just want to get the row when I pass the code 3123123123.

I tried below native query, but it is not replacing the parameter with the actual value.

Below is the query which I have constructed.

`public static final String FIND_ITEM_BY_BARCODE = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_stats -> 'barcodes' @> '[{\\\"code\\\"\\: ?1}]'";`

Below is the Repo call.

`@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = MyConstants.FIND_ITEM_BY_BARCODE) ItemEntity findByBarcode(String barcode);`

Below is the error that I am getting.

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json\n  Detail: Token "\" is invalid.\n  Position: 67\n  Where: JSON data, line 1: [{\..."}

Below is the query that the framework is creating.

SELECT
*
FROM
item
WHERE
item_stats -> 'barcodes' @> '[{"code": ?1}]'

Please help me find out a way to query the jsonB column.

I have looked into Stackoverflow but could not find any question that could help me and hence I am here writing the question.

Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a way to query which was fairly simple.
I created a String variable as below.

String jsonStr = "{\"barcodes\": [{\"code\": \""+barcodeValue+"\"}]}";

You can use String format() to format jsonStr and pass barcodeValue.
The query that worked for me is shared below:

"SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_stats @> cast(:secondaryBarcode as jsonb)";

The method in repo is kept unchanged.
findByBarcode(String secondaryBarcode);

I hope this will help somebody looking out to troubleshoot similar issue.

Comment: Be careful when using `+` to construct queries, especially if the `barcodeValue` is not generated by you.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that up. I don't think there will be any issue in my case since it is an in-house product and the front end team will do their validation before sending it to the back end. Also, only the barcode value is getting concatenated and the whole string will be passed a parameter to the query. 
There won't be any SQL injection. I have also added the length check on the input barcode. 
Thank you again for bringing this to my attention.